# Javascript Easiest/Most Elegant way of using a loading gif

Tags: javascript, html, loading

I want to show a modal loading gif while something is storing in a database.

I can figure out a way:

```
<div id='loading' class='loading hidden'>    
  <img src='assets/img/loadingbig.gif'></img>
</div>
```

Then i can  `$('#loading').removeClass('hidden');` when saving starts and  `$('#loading').addClass('hidden');` when saving ends.

Is this the best (easiest, best performance, most elegant) way of doing this?

Regards,

Comment: If the animation is simple, I would build the loader in pure CSS. If the animation is of significant enough complexity to require a gif, however, I would do almost exactly what you did here

Answer (score 0):

Well you're using jquery, so there's little need to stuff more properties in your css styles for a simple toggle. You can use $('#loading').show() and $('#loading').hide().

Answer (score 0):

I would make a fuction that uses javascripts timings, but use HTML To display the .gif. That is one of HTML's functions, is to display images.

Comment: I believe using the <img src= (location here)> </img> tag. I don't know. I use CSS to handle image tags mostly. Just display it on a page and then have it redirect it. I'm not the best on these kinds of things. Sorry :/